How i can show the Sum of Hours for a field for each User
I have create a Data source from an API inside PowerBI reports, as follow:-

the Data i am showing is as follow:-

with these fields; Name, LogStart, LogEnd, Type & TotalTime... now how i can show the Sum for the TotalTime field for each Name? also this should work for filtered data? Can anyone advice?
Thanks
